# Extracting elements from a list of list

Tags: python, list

I have a dataset which is a list and its elements are again a list. 
For example, myList = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],.......,[7,8,9],[11,12,14]]. I want to randomly pick a bunch of elements from this list - say,[4,5,6] and [11,12,14]. How to achieve this?

I tried the following:

```
# Suppose List_1 has 1000 elements(lists) and I want 100 elements
indices = np.random.choice(myList, size = 100, replace = None )
new_list = myList[indices]
```

Apparently, the above code does not work. The error message is: "list indices must be integers or slices, not list"

Can anyone help me with this? My actual intention is to sample data points(lists) from the original dataset(list) to create a batch of data for training an ML algorithm.

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to use numpy for this? You can just use [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice)

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) which takes an additional parameter to specify the number of random items to select from population:

```
import random

myList = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[11,12,14]]
print(random.sample(myList, 2))
```

Comment: Suppose I have two lists: myList1 (Ex: input data) and myList2 (Ex: output data) each having the same number of elements (which are lists) and with a 1-1 correspondence. Is there a way I can sample the elements randomly from these two lists so that the extracted elements have the same index?

Answer (score 0):

You Can consider random - Random variable generators, Where as if you are looking  to pick any number of list element then as @Austin suggested use `sample` with random but the fair choice is random.

**Using `random.sample` would be ...**

```
>>> lst
[['15', '48', '698'], ['10', '32', '66'], ['78', '501', '23']]

>>> random.sample(population=lst, k=2)
[['78', '501', '23'], ['15', '48', '698']]
```

**While using** `random.choices`

```
>>> random.choices(population=lst, k=2)
[['15', '48', '698'], ['15', '48', '698']]
```

**Note**

Look at [The random Doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)  here

> random.sample(population, k) Return a k length list of unique elements
>   chosen from the population sequence or set. Used for random sampling
>   without replacement.
>
> random.choices(population, weights=None, *, cum_weights=None, k=1)
>   Return a k sized list of elements chosen from the population with
>   replacement. If the population is empty, raises IndexError.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in last line but still I think it's closest to what you intended ( using numpy )

```
indices = np.random.choice(range(len(myList)), size = 100, replace = None )
new_list = myList[indices]
```

Comment: Yes, I made an error while posting it here. I have edited the post now. Thanks

Comment: but still extracting indices of chosen elements using this syntax is alternative without using sample